# How to add ngRoute as a Dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to use $routeParams in my js, but I receive the error that $routeParams has an unknown provider. I have installed angular-route into my node_modules, but I do not know how to make it a dependency in my js. Here is my js:

```
function ClientCtrl($scope, $http,$routeParams) {
  $scope.clients = [];
  $http.get('/client').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.clients = data;
    if (data == "") {
      $scope.clients = [];
    }
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Ops: could not get any data");
  });
  $scope.client=$scope.clients[$routeParams.id]

  $scope.addClient = function() {
    $http.post('/client', {
        name : $scope.clientName,
        age : $scope.clientAge,
        birthday : $scope.clientBirthday,
        notes : $scope.clientNotes,


    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.clients.push({
        name : $scope.clientName,
        age : $scope.clientAge,
        birthday : $scope.clientBirthday,
        notes : $scope.clientNotes,
        });
        $scope.clientName = '';
        $scope.clientAge = '';
        $scope.clientBirthday = '';
        $scope.clientNotes = '';
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Ops: " + data);
    });
  };
  $scope.edit = function(client) {
  $scope.current = client;
};
$scope.current = {};
```

}

I've also included the script into my index.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/todo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/viewcontroller.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.done-true {
text-decoration: line-through;
color: grey;
}</style>
</head>
```

UPDATE: When injecting into my app.js, I receive error that "window is not defined"

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var models = require("./models");
var app = express();
var database = require('./models');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
app.get('/', routes.login);
app.get('/client', routes.getclients);
app.post('/client', routes.saveclients);
database.sequelize
.authenticate()
.then(function(err) {
console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}, function (err) {
console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
models.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include a path to the ngRoute file in your `index.html` file and inject the module in your `app.js`:

```
<script src="path/to/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And in the

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) for a complete explanation

Comment: When I inject into app.js, I receive the error that "window" is not defined

Comment: @AaronOberländer can you edit your question to include the complete error?

Comment: @AaronOberländer You are using two different versions which, 99 times out of 100, will cause issues. Not to mention you are using a very old beta version of Angular. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/**1.3.0-beta.5**/angular.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/**1.5.5**/angular-route.js"></script>`.

Comment: @Lex Which version should I bring it to, I am not seeing a version 1.5.5?

Comment: @AaronOberländer Google's failure to maintain their own CDN is frustrating. If you are set on using a CDN, I recommend [this one](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/1.5.5).

Comment: @Lex <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script> I added this, but it now says all my controllers are not functions

Comment: That is a typo, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112333/discussion-between-aaron-oberlander-and-lex).

Comment: @AaronOberländer SO's chat functionality is blocked for me at work. :(

Comment: @Lex Ahh, I see. Well, when adding any version of angular other than the one I have, I receive the error "angular is not defined", which refers to my js where I have angular.module...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ngRoute` as a dependency to your module and then add your controller to that module.

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('ClientController', 
['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  // Your code
}]);
```